# How do I prevent Flutter Web from using Canvaskit?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, canvaskit

My Flutter Web app loads very slowly. When checking the network section of DevTools I see that this is caused by the massive `canvaskit.wasm` file. I assume this is because Flutter is using the canvaskit web renderer instead of the html web renderer. How can I change this behaviour?

I have already tried building with

```
flutter build web --web-renderer html
```

but it has no effect.

As suggested by Flutter [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/web-renderers#runtime-configuration), I have also tried overriding the renderer at runtime by inserting

```
<script>
    window.flutterWebRenderer = "html";
</script>
```

above `<script src="main.dart.js"...`. But, this also has no effect. `canvaskit.wasm` still tries to load and brings everything to a grinding halt.

What else can I do? Is it even possible to prevent Flutter from requesting CanvasKit files?

(Note: I delete all the cache and app data from the browser between tests to ensure I'm not just loading the previous build)